# Add MS-Outlook Group Calendar to SharePoint Site Home Page

Tags: sharepoint-online, outlook

I have a SharePoint Site for Business Development and they want their group calendar added to the empty space.  The problem I'm having is multi-faceted:
1) All the suggestions I've been given include clicking a "+" when editing a page that is in modern view, but our home pages seem to be in classic view.[image]

2) I cannot find "embed group calendar" in any of the options listed here.  I've looked in both App Part and Web Part.

3) I'm unable to figure out how to make this home page in modern view.

**If possible provide a no code solution**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [Office 365 groups](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/learn-about-office-365-groups-b565caa1-5c40-40ef-9915-60fdb2d97fa2), you can use a Group Calendar web part on a modern page to view the calendar of this group. The Group Calendar web part only works in the modern pages and you cannot find this web part in the classic page. Use a modern page instead of the classic page.

How to create a modern page:

1. Open Site Pages library;
2. Create a Site Page, it is a modern page.

[image]

Comment: Joanna,

Thank-you for your reply.  I created the page, added the "group calendar" web part, and then that was it- I wasn't able to go any further.  There was an option on the right to add the group "Outlook Customer Manager".  That brought me to an entirely new challenge, how to create a group (via outlook) using an email address that is already in use.

Frankly, I'm giving up.